# Añadir etiqueta script en HTML mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un proyecto en HTML estático el cual está alojado en un repositorio desde el cual se despliega en 2 dominios diferentes.

El problema que tengo es que dependiendo del dominio, debe cargar un script de una web externa

Desde el dominio 1 tiene que cargar esto:

```
<script src="https://webexterna.org/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="12356-123456" ></script>
```

Desde el dominio 2 tiene que cargar esto:

```
<script src="https://otrawebexterna.org/otroscript.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="23222333-111222" ></script>
```

Y después ejecutar una función

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function damedatos() { }
    </script>
```

Utilizando esto para el primer dominio

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src ="https://webexterna.org/script.js"";
script.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
script.setAttribute("data-domain-script", "12356-123456");
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var script2 = document.createElement( "script" );
script2.type = "text/javascript";
script2.text = "function damedatos() { }";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scrip2t);
```

me agrega la etiqueta, pero la función no la ejecuta.

¿Alguna idea?

Salu2

Comment: Hola. De verdad no la está ejecutando¿?? como lo sabes¿?? porque ahí estás creando una función vacía y luego no la llamas, prueba a esa función entroducirle un console.log() o algo y hacer la llamada a esa función

Answer (score 3):

No estás ejecutando la función, estás definiendola

```js
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.innerHTML = 'function damedatos(){alert("se está ejecutando")}'
document.head.append(script)

damedatos(); //<-- Aqui se ejecuta lo que fue cargado
```

Answer (score 0):

si yo pongo a fuego esto en la cabecera, muestra un popup

```
<script src="https://webexterna.org/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="12356-123456" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function damedatos() { }
</script>
```

si lo hago a través de JavaScript, añade las etiquetas pero no muestra nada.

La función está definida así en los datos originales.

Comentar, que las funciones javascript están dentro de

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

});
```